# Does scanf() not read EOF?

Tags: c

I was writting a program that is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int char_value(int);

void main()
{
    int ch;
    printf("Enter characters : ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    for (printf("Letter is_Letter letter_Postion\n"); ch!=EOF; scanf("%c", &ch))
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
            printf("   %-3c %-9s      %d\n", ch, "   Yes", char_value(toupper(ch)));
        else if (isspace(ch))
            printf("#SPACE %-9s      N/A\n", "   No");
        else if (!isgraph(ch))
            printf("#BLANK %-9s      N/A", "   No");
        else
            printf("   %-3c %-9s      N/A\n", ch, "   No");
    }
}

int char_value(int ch)
{
    return ch-64;
}
```

in which the for loop was not terminating, but when I replaced the `scanf()` with `getchar()` that is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int char_value(int);

void main()
{
    int ch;
    printf("Enter characters : ");
    ch=getchar();
    for (printf("Letter is_Letter letter_Postion\n"); ch!=EOF; ch=getchar())
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
            printf("   %-3c %-9s      %d\n", ch, "   Yes", char_value(toupper(ch)));
        else if (isspace(ch))
            printf("#SPACE %-9s      N/A\n", "   No");
        else if (!isgraph(ch))
            printf("#BLANK %-9s      N/A", "   No");
        else
            printf("   %-3c %-9s      N/A\n", ch, "   No");
    }
}

int char_value(int ch)
{
    return ch-64;
}
```

then the program was working as expected. Why this is happening? Does `scanf()` not read `EOF`?

Comment: Check what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) ***returns***.

Comment: `EOF` is not a character as such, it is a *condition* that is set when we reach the end of an input stream.  Both `scanf` and `getchar` *return* `EOF` to indicate that there’s no more input on the stream.

Answer (score 2):

No, since `EOF` is not a character, `scanf` doesn't set `ch` to `EOF`.

Quoted from the [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/#return) documentation:

> **Return value**
>   On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

Applied to your case: You need to examine the return-code of `scanf("%c", &ch)`:

- If it is 1, then `ch` is set.
- If it is 0, then `ch` is undefined.

Comment: With `scanf("%c", &ch)` , "if it is 0" is not expected.  A return value of `EOF` is expected (with `ch` unchanged) on end-of-file.  A return value of `EOF` is expected (with `ch` indeterminate) on error.  Your reference has "If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set .... And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned."

Comment: If `EOF` does not behave like character then how `getchar()` reads it and assign it to `ch` ?

Comment: @RaviRaj `EOF` is an `int` (`-1`), and thus outside the `char` range (`0x00` ... `0xff`). Therefore `int getchar()` is able to return a `char` and also `EOF` if nothing was read.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You mean that `scanf()` will never return 0?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Can you give an example in which `scanf()` return 0 as I can't think one.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for clearing my confusion.

Comment: @RaviRaj Comment cleaner (since [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571256/does-scanf-not-read-eof/51571351?noredirect=1#comment112009253_51571351)) coming though